# Выход из бесконечного цикла без команды ввода

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, c++14

Реально ли сделать выход из цикла без команды ввода? Допустим идет бесконечный цикл и в любой момент я нажимаю ENTER и цикл прекращается.
Если и да, то каким образом?

```
for (int repeat = 0; repeat <= 1; repeat--) {

                system("color 07");
                Beep(2233, 500);
                system("color 70");
                Sleep(400);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас установленна библиотека **conio** (нет в std), вполне подойдет старый добрый `kbhit()`:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        system("color 07");
        Beep(2233, 500);
        system("color 70");
        Sleep(400);

        if(kbhit())
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Если такой библиотеки нет, то можно [без труда](https://cboard.cprogramming.com/linux-programming/27736-detecting-esc-any-other-key-kbhit-alternative.html) найти кастомный вариант такой же, по смыслу, функции в интернетах.

PS Предыдущий оратор правильно заметил, что в вашем примере цикл не бесконечен.

Comment: Ответ был настолько прост.. 
Спасибо!

Answer (score 7):

Приведённый Вами цикл не является бесконечным. Когда `repeat` достигнет минимального значения, при очередной попытке уменьшить его произойдёт underflow, что, кстати, вызовет неопределённое поведение программы.

```
for (int repeat = 0; repeat <= 1; repeat--)
```

Вот пример, работающий на Linux:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>


int main()
{
    std::atomic<bool> run = true;

    std::thread stopper([&](){ std::cin.ignore(); run = false; });

    while (run)
    {
        // Ваш код
    }

    stopper.join();
}
```

Мы запускаем отдельный поток, в котором вызываем чтение стандартного ввода. Эта операция блокирует поток. При нажатии на <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, поток просыпается, игнорирует ввод и устанавливает переменную `run` в значение `false`.

При этом основной поток обнаружит, что `run == false` и прекратит выполнение цикла `while`. После этого мы дожидаемся правильного завершения запущенного ранее потока, и программа завершается.